Validation of downscaled imagery
I apologize in advance if the post is not suitable for this site. If so, then feel free to recommend other relevant sites and I'll close the question.
Imagine a sensor (let's call it sensor A) that captures images in two viewing angles, near-nadir (NN) and off-nadir (ON). The task is to downscale (DS) the images. Assuming, for validation, there is another sensor (sensor B) that captures images in the same wavelength as the sensor A. Sensor's B images are not regular in terms of temporal resolution and it can acquire images for a specific region from different viewing angles (VA). In the metadata of sensor B images, the VA is not mentioned.
How would you approach the task of validating the DS images from sensor A using the sensor B? What I'm trying to say is that "traditional" validation tests (i.e., r-squared or RMSE) might not be appropriate because (to me at least) it's like comparing apples to oranges. What I mean is that if I am to compare the DS image from the NN VA against the image from sensor B, and the later image is taken from a NN position, then it makes sense that the r-squared will be higher compared to the ON vs Sensor B.
What are your recommendations?
